# vBulletin: Installing the CMS Folder

Tags: content-management-system, vbulletin

I have installed vB 4.1.9. Well the package came with two folders: "do not upload" and "upload". Before I upload it to my server, I am using MAMP Pro to get a feel of vB.

I have upload all the contents in "upload" and ran the install. It went well: "http://localhost:8888/forums/forum.php". I have looked at other vB forums and I see a home page, I assume thats the content page: https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/content.php

I have no idea what to do with that cms folder in the do not upload folder. My webpage only has the "forum" page.

Any tips?

Comment: You do not upload it, as it is in the `do_not_upload` folder. Did you purchase the full CMS license or just the forum?

Answer (score 0):

The following [post](https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/383812-CMS-to-root-domain?highlight=do_not_upload/cms) on the vBulletin forums mentions the folder `do_not_upload/cms` (3rd answer). I guess it has something to do with getting your CMS to your root domain.

This [other one](https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/371680-VB-4-1-1-Doesn-t-work?highlight=do_not_upload/cms) too.

---

Just for infor, the folder `do_not_upload`is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/):

> The second folder is **do_not_upload** - This folder contains tools to perform various tasks on your board
>
> - searchshell.php - This file will allow you to rebuild the search index.
> - vb_backup.sh - This file will allow you to run a database backup via SSH/Telnet or a scheduled backup through cron.
> - tools.php - This file must be uploaded to the admincp folder and allows you to perform certain tasks should your board go down or you accidentally lock yourself out of the Admin Control Panel. This file must be deleted immediately after use or it will cause a SEVERE security problem.